# Can I use the old and not used anymore furnace chimney to vent out my basement?

Tags: ventilation, chimney

My chimney is not used anymore.
Would it be possible or recommended to use it to vent the basement ? 
I would clean it and install a fan at the basement end.

thanks

Comment: It's usually easier to just install a vent out the side of the house, as you would for a clothes dryer.

Comment: That wall is already like a Swiss cheese and it is starting to form cracks I do not want to put any more holes into it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You don't have to clean it & seal the fireplace up or was non-existent. Meaning, the chimney was just for a basement gas appliance or fixture. Natural convection will do it's thing, but a little fan won't hurt, small bath sized exhaust fan 50CFM.